# What is the law for sites like Fiverr in using purchased "creative works"

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, ownership

So [Fiverr](https://www.fiverr.com/) for those that aren't familiar is a site for buying and selling creative works essentially, from freelance artists. On [some of them](https://www.fiverr.com/gvilava/record-a-georgian-male-voice-over) you can "add on" either (a) "Commercial Use Rights", or (b) "Full Broadcasting Rights". Most authors don't seem to mind about these things and instead make copyright free works and when asked will say "Of course you can use this however you like" sorts of things.

Meanwhile, there are the lawyers saying everything needs to be in a contract. Fiverr doesn't have any "contracts" other than your purchased transaction if that counts. You're left to wonder if you need to go out beyond and write up a "Content License Agreement" sort of thing that officially outlines everything in legalese.

My question is, broadly, what are the rules/laws for sites like Fiverr in terms of using the content you purchase? Doesn't purchasing it mean you have full rights to it?

If not, then what actions must be taken to ensure you have "full rights" to the content? Purchasing these "addons" hardly seems like a robust solution, would that even hold up? Does asking them casually in chat "Hey, can I use your content for commercial purposes?" and them answering "Yes of course :)" count as a contract? I think it does, but maybe I'm wrong. And if they instead say "No, you cannot use it for commercial purposes", what do you do then? Or perhaps they say "No, but if you buy my extra gig you can get the commercial license", how do you make this binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You mean [this](https://www.fiverr.com/terms_of_service) contract that you definitely agreed to?

The ones that says:

> When purchasing a Gig, Buyers are granted all rights for the delivered work, unless otherwise specified by the Seller on their Gig page. Note: some Gigs charge additional payments (through Gig Extras) for Commercial Use License. See our “Ownership” and “Commercial Use License” sections below for more information.

Comment: I was reading that but I want to make sure there are no loopholes.

Comment: Does this mean if they don't list it by the time I buy the gig, that I can use it for whatever?